# llply progress bar when parallel mode

Tags: r, parallel-processing, progress-bar, plyr, progress

I'm using  to `llply` to apply a function to ~1500 list. Each function takes ~5 mins to apply. When I run in parallel mode the .progress is disable understandably to speedup the process, is there a way to monitor the progress of `llply` in parallel mode ?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `dplyr`? It's the tops

Comment: Its been a little over than a month. Have you found a solution to this? I am trying to find something